# How to implement Kurento one to one video call tutorial with websocket Sip servlet

Tags: java, servlets, webrtc, kurento, mobicents-sip-servlets

Here is my work till now

Mobicents SIP server is running a websocket-sip-servlet for WebRTC client registration and proxy. with Sipml5 WebRTC client i had registerd and make a call audio/video after registering succesfully.

Kurento tutorial one to one video call from git is running too

kurento media server is runnig fine on port 8888.

What i'm trying,

On the doResponse of websocket-sip-servlet java file,

I'm trying to create a kurento media pipeline and send sdp of registered user to Kurento media server to get sdp response and send to registered user for media session.

similary with other user,

and later on when a one caller call to calle the video call should be established via Kurento media server.

May be my concepts were wrong or question may be wrong, please suggest me how can i achieve my task, suggestion, guiding, tutoring all are heartily welcome. Thanks in advance.